# celery beat using celery-django not working

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

i am new to celery-django library and i try to config and use it with rabbitmq, all configurations is right but i still have a problem in celery beat, when i run it using this command :

```
python manage.py celeryd -l info -B --settings=settings.settings
```

i got this messeges in the log :

```
[2019-05-14 15:20:56,288: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...

[2019-05-14 15:20:56,292: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...

[2019-05-14 15:20:56,921: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//

[2019-05-14 15:20:56,965: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors

[2019-05-14 15:20:58,041: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone

[2019-05-14 15:20:58,086: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-3gb-sgp1-01 ready.

[2019-05-14 15:21:01,407: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...

[2019-05-14 15:24:06,332: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: What command are you using to run celery?

Comment: python manage.py celeryd -l info -B --settings=settings.settings

Comment: is this celery version 4.x?

Comment: version : 3.1.23

Comment: Whats happening is that your worker is running beat but no worker is processing any entries. you need to run `python manage.py celery worker --beat`

Comment: Also, upgrade to celery 4.x, this version you are using isnt supported anymore

Comment: i got this messege 
[2019-05-14 15:37:48,400: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-3gb-sgp1-01 ready.

Comment: Congrats! This means your worker is running and ready to receive tasks!

Comment: Not sure why its logged as a warning though. Is it waiting for a periodic task to run?

Comment: yes, but in log still this messege appears

[2019-05-14 15:40:40,877: INFO/Beat] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
[2019-05-14 15:40:40,878: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2019-05-14 15:43:25,832: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...

Comment: Any reason why you are still using this old version of celery?

Comment: not my desissuion but its legacy code and i have a plan to update libraries, but its should works regardles the version

Comment: Im assuming you are using this with django? if so what version? and what version of rabbitmq are you on?

Comment: django 2.7 , rabbitmq is the latest.

Comment: u mean django 2.1.7?

Comment: oh sorry django 1.8 but python 2.7